# How to display the index-number of the current box

Tags: tex-core, boxes, box

In LaTeX (or maybe in TeX), how one can get notified about the "index" to the current LaTeX or TeX-box?

For example, say an empty page is created in LaTeX; we firstly add a paragraph and then a figure to the page. Now, how to get (and preferably display) the "index" number to the current "box"?

Comment: That's not possible, if I understood what you want. TeX doesn't count how many boxes it has output (there are _thousands_), so you don't have access to this information. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no index of boxes created, what is your actual aim here?

Comment: Firstly, I need the order of the boxes, and secondly, to know how many boxes were created on a page by the TeX. The current box we are using or working on it, is the last box that was created by TeX. I'm Asking is there a way to count boxes or not?

Comment: @Qaher Short answer: no. At the time TeX actually ships out a box, it has already processed all the “TeX code” and is just putting things in the output file, so you have no counters anymore. You can, however, get a rough estimate of how many boxes you have by counting the total number of characters, plus the number of lines, plus the number of pages, plus eventual headers and footers (plus characters and lines therein). Those are the obvious ones. If you do `\loggingoutput` you will see more

Comment: tex has no record of these things even internally, boxes are _values_ not declared constructs, so asking how many boxes have been used is like asking how many integers have been used or how many times `a` has been used. In some abstract sense the question has a numeric answer but it just isn't a value that is ever tracked or available.